# How to make a custom font load faster on website instead of downloading whole font every time?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I use a custom font on my website, Hestia.market, and because the browser has to download the whole font every time it takes a very long time to load. I normally just use google fonts api and so speed hasn't been a problem for me before. How would I make the font load faster?